# Adding 3 blank rows when value changes in excel column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to enter 3 blank rows whenever the value in column A changes. I found the following vba code online. Is it possible to adapt this to get it to enter 3 instead of 1 row? I also would like to get rid of the input box. My knowledge of vba is very limited so I apologize for that.

I just need some way to enter 3 blank rows whenever the value in the ID column changes without any sort of input box or other dialogue box. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Dim curR As Range
Set curR = Application.Selection
Set curR = Application.InputBox("Select the Range of Cells to be insert blank rows", xTitleId, curR.Address, Type:=8)
For i = curR.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If curR.Cells(i, 1).Value <> curR.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        curR.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0GC9.png)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure below will allow you to specify how many rows you want to insert after each change. You can also specify another ID column, simply by changing the value of the constant `TargetClm`.

```
Sub Insert3Rows()
    ' 298

    Const TargetClm As String = "A"     ' change to suit
    Const NumRows   As Integer = 3      ' number of rows to insert
    Dim R           As Long             ' loop counter: sheet rows
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")           ' change to suit
        ' loop from next to last used cell to row 2
        For R = (.Cells(.Rows.Count, TargetClm).End(xlUp).Row - 1) To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, TargetClm).Value <> .Cells(R + 1, TargetClm).Value Then
                .Cells(R + 1, TargetClm).Resize(NumRows).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

No provision has been made to handle blank rows. Therefore, please don't run the code twice on the same worksheet.

Comment: This works almost perfectly... thank you so much! The only thing is that I would like 3 rows to be inserted between the first and second row. Is there a simple adaptation that can be made? As it stands now, there are no blanks between the first and second rows of filled cells. @Variatus

Comment: Please try `.Cells(R + 2, TargetClm).Resize(NumRows).EntireRow.Insert`, where `R+1` is replaced with `R+2`. The result looks funny to me but it appears to match your description.